# Android application with PhoneGap and struts2

Tags: android, jakarta-ee, struts2, struts, cordova

I have a Java EE web application developped with strut2.

Now I want make Android mobile client and I dont want to touch to business and persistence layer.

So I want to change the presentation layer without changing business layer. is it possible with phonegap? is possible to call struts2 actions with phonegap ?

Answer (score 2):

PhoneGap is designed to run HTML/CSS/JavaScript locally on the device. It sounds like you should be writing an HTML5 offline-capable Web app.